# How's my and my father's java ODE Solving and Graphing Program?

Tags: java, beginner, layout

At the request of my father, I've adapted some C# code he wrote which uses a timer to display the true and approximate solutions of the ODE y' = -lambda*y in real time to do the same in java and then graph the solutions using JFreeChart. The approximate solution is Euler's (first order) method. I don't have much programming experience and I'm looking for some feedback (efficiency, best practice, layout, design). One question in particular I'd like to know the answer to is whether or not JFreeChart is a good choice? Is there a better one? I'm also particularly interested in receiving feedback concerning the efficiency and quality of my design and layout. Here's the code, which takes the form of 2 classes (ODESolver and Graph) which use JCommon-1.0.20 and JFreeChart-1.0.16:

ODESolver.java:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import org.eclipse.wb.swing.FocusTraversalOnArray;

/**
*
* @author George and Stephen Tomlinson
*/


public class ODESolver extends JFrame {

    // Declarations.

    // serialVersionUID sets the version number. 

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Declare a JPanel to define and manipulate the contents of the ODESolver GUI.

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private static JTextField a0;
    private static JTextField lambda;
    private static JTextField timeStep;
    private static final int TOTAL_SECONDS = 20;
    private double elapsedSeconds = 0;
    private Timer myTimer = new Timer(0, (ActionListener) null);
    JTextArea timerLabel = new JTextArea();
    JTextArea trueSol = new JTextArea();
    static JTextArea apprxSol = new JTextArea();
    double aoD;
    double lambdaD;
    double timeStepD, state1, state2, ans1, timeLeft;
    double roundOff, roundOffA;
    String t, tA;
    ArrayList<Double> true_A = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> apprx_A = new ArrayList<Double>();
    private static JTextField timerInterval;
    int timerInt;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Run the ODESolver code in the Event-dispatching thread for thread-safety
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // try to create an instance of ODESolver (which extends JFrame) and make it visible
                // print the StackTrace if there's a problem
                try {
                    ODESolver frame = new ODESolver(); // let the constructor do the work
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * This is the constructor method. It creates the frame. (ODESolver extends the class JFrame).
     */
    public ODESolver() {

        // Form specification (what to do when form is closed, dimensions, instantiate contentPane, 
        // dimensions of contentPane, set ContentPane property (hover over it for more details).

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 892, 400);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        // Create text field for entering a0 (10 columns by default).

        a0 = new JTextField();
        a0.setColumns(10);

        // Create label for text field ao.

        JLabel lblA = new JLabel("a0");
        lblA.setLabelFor(a0);
        lblA.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        // Create label for text field lambda.

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("lambda");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        // Create text field for entering lambda. 

        lambda = new JTextField();
        lblNewLabel.setLabelFor(lambda);
        lambda.setColumns(10);

        // Create label for text field time step.

        JLabel lblTimeStep = new JLabel("time step");
        lblTimeStep.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        // Create text field for entering time step.

        timeStep = new JTextField();
        lblTimeStep.setLabelFor(timeStep);
        timeStep.setColumns(10);

        // Create label for 'Simulation time' text area.

        JLabel lblSimulationTime = new JLabel("Simulation time");
        lblSimulationTime.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        // Create text area to show true soln and prevent the user form being able to edit it.

        trueSol.setEditable(false);
        trueSol.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        // Create label for text area true soln.

        JLabel lblSolutiontrue = new JLabel("Solution 1 (true)");
        lblSolutiontrue.setLabelFor(trueSol);
        lblSolutiontrue.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        // Create text area apprx soln. 

        //JT[2] = apprxSol;
        apprxSol.setEditable(false);
        apprxSol.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        // Create label for text area apprx soln.

        JLabel lblSolutionapprx = new JLabel("Solution 2 (apprx)");
        lblSolutionapprx.setLabelFor(apprxSol);
        lblSolutionapprx.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        // Create 'Start the simulation' button.

        JButton btnStartTimer = new JButton("Start the simulation");
        btnStartTimer.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        /*
         *
        Set its function. The ActionListener class possesses one method (by the name of 'ActionPerformed')
        which is invoked when an action occurs i.e. the button is clicked. This  is in java.awt: one of the
        2 packages in the standard library (Java Standard Edition 7 API (Java SE 7 API for short)) used for 
        creating GUIs. The other one is called javax.swing.  
         *
         */

        btnStartTimer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                // Parse and store user input.

                aoD = Double.parseDouble(getA0().getText());
                lambdaD = Double.parseDouble(getLambda().getText());
                timeStepD = Double.parseDouble(getTimeStep().getText());
                timerInt = Integer.parseInt(getTimerInterval().getText());

                // If the button has been pressed and the timer is already running, stop the timer,
                // initialise myTimer and instruct user to press the button again to start a new simulation.

                if (myTimer != null && myTimer.isRunning()) {
                   myTimer.stop();
                   myTimer = null;
                   timerLabel.setText("Press again for new sim");  

                // Else initialise elapsedSeconds, create a new timer and start it.

                } else {
                   elapsedSeconds = 0;
                   /*
                      Create a new Timer which uses the subclass TimerListener to compute and store the 
                      exact and approximate solutions of the differential equation (see further down for
                      definition of TimerListener.
                    */
                   myTimer = new Timer(timerInt, new TimerListener());
                   myTimer.start();
                }
             }
          });

        // End of code relating to 'Start the simulation' button. 

        // Create a label for the timer. 

        timerLabel = new JTextArea();
        timerLabel.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        timerLabel.setEditable(false);

        // Create 'Draw graph' button.

        JButton btnDraw = new JButton("Draw graph");
        btnDraw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // Store the true and apprx solution data sets in an ArrayList array called i.
                ArrayList[] i = new ArrayList[2];
                i[0] = true_A;
                i[1] = apprx_A;
                // Instantiate a Graph object and call its createAndShowGUI method to produce the GUI
                // containing the desired graph.
                Graph graph = new Graph();
                graph.createAndShowGUI(i);

            }
        });
        btnDraw.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        // End of code relating to 'Draw Graph' button.

        // Create label for timer interval text field.

        JLabel lblTimerInterval = new JLabel("timer interval");
        lblTimerInterval.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        // Create timer interval JTextField.

        timerInterval = new JTextField();
        timerInterval.setColumns(10);

        /*
           The following code is automatically generated by WindowBuilderPro in response to operations
           performed using the visual editor (the equivalent of the Designer code in C#). Actually some
           of the other code is also generated by WBP in the same way: i.e. declaration and 
           specification of JTextFields, JButtons and JTextAreas above and below. The definitions of
           the methods (except methods like getTimeStep() below) are left to the programmer.
         * 
         */

        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(139)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(lblTimerInterval)
                                .addComponent(lblTimeStep)
                                .addComponent(lblNewLabel)
                                .addComponent(lblA))
                            .addGap(18)
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(a0, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(lambda, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(timeStep, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGap(37)
                                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(trueSol, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(apprxSol, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(timerLabel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                .addComponent(timerInterval, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(btnStartTimer, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 226, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(btnDraw)))
                    .addGap(83)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lblSolutiontrue)
                        .addComponent(lblSimulationTime)
                        .addComponent(lblSolutionapprx))
                    .addContainerGap(362, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(11)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblA)
                                .addComponent(a0, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lblSimulationTime))
                            .addGap(17))
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(timerLabel, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)))
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(lambda, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(trueSol, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(lblSolutiontrue))
                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel))
                    .addGap(14)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(timeStep, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblSolutionapprx)
                        .addComponent(apprxSol, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(lblTimeStep))
                    .addGap(18)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lblTimerInterval)
                        .addComponent(timerInterval, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(45)
                    .addComponent(btnStartTimer, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(29)
                    .addComponent(btnDraw)
                    .addGap(27))
        );
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
        contentPane.setFocusTraversalPolicy(new FocusTraversalOnArray(new Component[]{a0, lambda, timeStep}));
    }

    // method to get JTextField ao.

    public static JTextField getA0() {
        return a0;
    }

    // Method to get JTextField lambda.

    public static JTextField getLambda() {
        return lambda;
    }

    // Method to get JTextField timeStep.

    public static JTextField getTimeStep() {
        return timeStep;
    }

    // Subclass TimerListener used to compute and store exact and approximate solutions of the
    // differential equation when 'Start the simulation' button is pressed.

    public class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (elapsedSeconds == TOTAL_SECONDS) {
                myTimer.stop();
                timerLabel.setText("end");
             } else {
                String text = String.valueOf(elapsedSeconds);
                timerLabel.setText(text);
                    timeLeft = 20.0-elapsedSeconds;
                    if (elapsedSeconds != 20.0)
                            {
                                ans1 = Math.exp(-lambdaD * elapsedSeconds);
                                state1 = aoD * ans1; 
                                true_A.add(state1);

                                // true_A and apprx_A are objects of type ArrayList.
                                // true_A.add(state1) just stores the value of state1 at the next available
                                // space in true_A, which resizes dynamically.

                                 if (elapsedSeconds == 0.0)
                                    {
                                        // First point to add to the ArrayList containing the approx 
                                        // solution is the initial condition.

                                        state2 = aoD;
                                        apprx_A.add(state2);

                                    }
                                    else if (elapsedSeconds!=(0.0))
                                    {

                                        // Compute and add next point in approximate solution.

                                        // Compute approximate 1st order Euler solution.

                                        state2 = state2 - lambdaD * timeStepD * state2;  

                                        // Add the next point in the apprx solution.

                                        apprx_A.add(state2);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        /*
                                         If this point is reached, the method's not working properly,
                                         so display an error message detailing this and stop the 
                                         computation (return).
                                        */

                                        System.out.println("problem in if/else part of Start the simulation"
                                                + " method");
                                        return;
                                    }

                                    // Display the true and approximate solutions after first rounding
                                    // them to 2 decimal places.

                                    roundOff = Math.round(state1 * 100.0) / 100.0;
                                    t = String.valueOf(roundOff);
                                    trueSol.setText(t);

                                    roundOffA = Math.round(state2 * 100.0) / 100.0;
                                    tA = String.valueOf(roundOffA);
                                    apprxSol.setText(tA);

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                /*
                                 If this point is reached, the method's not working properly,
                                 so display an error message detailing this and stop the 
                                 computation (return).
                                  */
                                    System.out.println("problem: else part of Start the simulation"
                                            + " method reached");
                                    return;

                                }

             }
            // Increment elapsedSeconds by time step.
            elapsedSeconds+=timeStepD;
        }
     }

    // Method to get JTextField timerInterval.

    public static JTextField getTimerInterval() {
        return timerInterval;
    }
}
```

Graph.java

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYSplineRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;



/**
 *
 * @author George and Stephen Tomlinson
 */
public class Graph extends Applet{

    // set version number

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /*
       Method which takes an ArrayList array defining 2 data sets and produces a JFreeChart
       graphing them and adds this to a JPanel which is then used by the createandShowGUI method to 
       define the contents of a JFrame GUI and then display it. The method returns this JPanel.
     */

    public JPanel createContentPane(ArrayList[] in){

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        XYSeries seriesTrue = new XYSeries("True");
        XYSeries seriesApprx = new XYSeries("Approx");

        // Read input arguments and store in XYSeries objects.

         for(int i=0;i<in[0].size();i++)
         {
             double item = (double)in[0].get(i);
             seriesTrue.add(i,item);
         }

         for(int i=0;i<in[1].size();i++)
         {
             double item = (double)in[1].get(i);
             seriesApprx.add(i,item);
         }        

        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        XYSeriesCollection datasetApprx = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(seriesTrue);
        datasetApprx.addSeries(seriesApprx);

        // Create a chart from the first data set (the true solution). 

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                "Plot of true and approx solns of y' = -lambda*y",
                "time",
                "y",
                dataset, 
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false
                );

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);

        // Add the second data set (the approximate solution) to the chart (the first is at index 0).

        chart.getXYPlot().setDataset(1, datasetApprx);

        /*
         Create a separate renderer for each data set (otherwise they won't be recognised as separate
         data sets, so the JFreeChart object won't give them different colours for example, as it only
         sees one data set, so refuses to assign any more than one colour to it.  
         * */

        XYSplineRenderer SR0 = new XYSplineRenderer(1000);

        XYSplineRenderer SR1 = new XYSplineRenderer(1000);

        chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(0, SR0); 

        chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(1, SR1); 

        // Set colours for each data set.

        chart.getXYPlot().getRendererForDataset(chart.getXYPlot().getDataset(0)).setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);

        chart.getXYPlot().getRendererForDataset(chart.getXYPlot().getDataset(1)).setSeriesPaint(0, Color.RED);

        panel.add(chartPanel);

        panel.setOpaque(true); 

        return panel;  
    }

    // Method to create the GUI upon which the graph is displayed, which takes an ArrayList array (called i)
    // of length 2 containing the 2 data sets to be graphed.

    public void createAndShowGUI(ArrayList[] i) {

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(" ODESolver ");

        // Create and set up the content pane.
        Graph demo = new Graph();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane(i));

        // The other bits and pieces that define how the JFrame will work and what it will look like.
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1300, 650);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Graph class does not compile in the line

```
double item = (double)in[1].get(i);
```

you cannot convert Object to double. **You should make sure that the code compiles before you show it to code review**. Other notes:

- You should not use unreadable constructs like the first element of an
  array means something and the other elements mean something
  different.
- Always use generics, not ArrayLists without a type
- JFreeChart is fine.
- You are also using
  org.eclipse.wb.swing.FocusTraversalOnArray as an external dependency
  (probably inserted by your GUI designer). GUI designers make your life easier when you are starting, but harder when you need to maintain/deploy your programs.

Comment: Yes. I had noted the ArrayList without type as an area to improve. Actually, the ArrayList does have a type. It's the ArrayList array which stores these ArrayLists that I haven't worked out how to give a matching type to yet (it should be Double). I don't think I have any cases where the first element of an array means something different to the others. If so, where?

Comment: It may be worth my pointing out that it's ODESolver.java that is supposed to be run. This then instantiates a Graph object. Graph does still compile for me though and even runs an applet, not that the applet does anything much. I guess the first element of an array maening something different to the others you wrote of might be apprx_A which stores the approximate solution in which case the first element must store the initial condition which is why it's not dealt wqith the same as the other elements. teh initial conditon is specified by the user, whilst the other elements of the approximate

Comment: solution are computed within ODESolver using Euler's (first order) method. I'm not sure if there' a better way of dealing with this.

Comment: The problems are in the createContentPane method of Graph. The argument is an array of ArrayLists, but these ArrayLists have raw type, not a generic declaration. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it). Perhaps you already corrected the declaration to createContentPane(ArrayList<Double>[] in) -- **note the Double!!** -- but posted some old code, while your version is working. I suppose in[0] means something else here than in[1].

Comment: That's got rid of the protocol warning (probably not the correct term: I mean the yellow warnings which don't prevent compilation) in Graph, but for the corresponding statement in ODESolver (ArrayList[] i = new ArrayList[2];) in the actionPerormed method of the button btnDraw I did try to change it accordingly before I posted this question to ArrayList<Double>[] i = new ArrayList<Double>[2]; but this results in the error 'cannot create a generic array of type Double'. I guess I might be forced to use a 2dArrayList if I want to get rid of the yellow warning.

Comment: in[0] is an ArrayList containing the 20 Doubles which store the y coordinates of the true solution. in[1] is the equavalent for the approximate solution. I realise I could make this clearer by choosing a better name than in.

Comment: I could compile and start your program after I changed to ArrayList<Double>[] in. I use Intellij Idea (not Eclipse) and Java 7. I would consider using a Point class that has  getX and getY methods - it would improve the readability a lot.

Comment: The x points are straight forward actually: since time is on the x axis, the x point is just the index in the ArrayList, so in[0].get(5) returns the y coordinate for the true solution at time 5 seconds (or more precisely 5 time units, since the timer interval can be changed by the user). I suppose it may be helpful to have the Point class and getY method though.

Comment: (time unit = timer interval)

Answer (score 2):

In addtion to @lbalazscs answers:

1. Your constructor is a gazillion lines long. Constructors should be kept short and precise so your can see quickly what it is doing. I'd move the code creating the UI out of there into one or more separate methods.
2. You mix UI and processing code. `ODESolver` should just do the processing of the values (basically do what the name of the class implies) and you should have a separate class (like `SolverDisplay`) dealing with the display concerns. Right now if someone wanted to change your solver or add stuff to it he'd have to wade through a ton of unrelated UI code just to find where you do the calculations. Not sure what the idiomatic Java approach for patterns like MVP or MVVM is but I'm sure there is information out there.

Comment: I don't actually know that I can reduce the constructor by that much: maybe the actionPerformed methods of the buttons could instantiate objects which deal with the workings of these methods. The rest of it is just declaring and setting up the various components of the UI and it was virtually all done automatically by the visual editor in WindowBuilderPro.

Comment: @bluesh34: In Winforms the designer generates a separate method `InitializeComponents()` where all the auto generated stuff is located in. Not sure how the WindowsBuilderPro would react if you were to do a similar thing.

Comment: I can just do the reverse anyway, as you suggest: move everything else elsewhere. Actually I think a more precise explanation of what happens with Winforms is that the auto-generated stuff is located in Designer.cs which is then called by InitializeComponent(), which is in Form.cs, but point taken: it may be possible to do the same in java.